# confusing OPTIONAL - disappearing records

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, option-type

I have problems with using the OPTIONAL phrase in the SPARQL statements. When I'm quering dbpedia like this:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?guitarist rdfs:label ?name . ?guitarist rdfs:comment ?desc . ?guitarist dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placebirth }
WHERE {
  ?guitarist dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_musical_artist> . 
  ?guitarist rdfs:label ?name .
  ?guitarist rdfs:comment ?desc .
  ?guitarist dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placebirth .
  FILTER ( lang(?name) = "en" && lang(?desc) = "en" )
}
```

Roger Waters birthplace and other data are returned. But when I turn it to this, all Roger_Waters records are missing:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?guitarist rdfs:label ?name . ?guitarist rdfs:comment ?desc . ?guitarist dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placebirth }
WHERE {
  ?guitarist dbpprop:wikiPageUsesTemplate <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_musical_artist> . 
  ?guitarist rdfs:label ?name .
  ?guitarist rdfs:comment ?desc .
  OPTIONAL { ?guitarist dbpprop:placeOfBirth ?placebirth }
  FILTER ( lang(?name) = "en" && lang(?desc) = "en" )
}
```

What I'm doing wrong - I suppose the complete records not to be missing after applying OPTIONAL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DBpedia endpoint returns partial results for queries that it deems too expensive.

Doing a `SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE …` with these two queries, it looks like the first query should return 8k results and the second should return 60k results. Your `CONSTRUCT` should generate 2-3 triples per result, so the first query should yield 16-24k triples, and the second should yield 120-180k. When I run the queries, I get the curious number of exactly 10001 triples from either query. So clearly the results are truncated.

Try `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` (possibly with an `ORDER BY`).

Comment: well, I tried to limit the results by adding ?guitarist dbpprop:shortDescription "British Musician" . constarint to the WHERE clause, but now it's returning an empty set (while according to http://dbpedia.org/page/Roger_Waters should be returned)